# what is the meaning of "what other safety" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Cops got alerted by disturbance from the Vampire house,
so they checking the house. Vampires disguise as humans 
when cops checking their house.

> Vampire#1: Let's kill them.
>
> Vampire#2: Well, let's just see **what other safety**. Stay here and then
>   maybe we'll.

I think "them" referred to cops.

Comment: Do you have a reference?  This sounds like something you misheard.

Comment: @Andrew I heard it correctly, no misheard here. It is from "What We Do in The Shadows (2014)" comedy movie.

Comment: Do you know about when in the movie they say this line?

Comment: It might be reasonable to close this because OP misheard what was actually said, but it's entirely specious to close it for being "opinion-based".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually (at about 52:00 in the movie) the vampire says:

> Well, let's just see what other safety **quips** they have, and then maybe we can (kill them).

The joke is that the police have been hypnotized by the vampires not to notice unusual things like floating people, dead bodies, blood, etc, but nevertheless they notice ordinary safety violations like the fact the house has no smoke detectors, improperly stored flammable liquids, etc.

There's also the additional joke that the vampires actually want to know what might be unsafe in their house, so they can fix it.  Then maybe, after they learn this useful information, they can kill the cops.

This is the kind of typical "dry" humor the writers (Flight of the Conchords) like to do, to show extraordinary situations in a mundane or ordinary way.

"Safety quips" might be a New Zealand expression, but I think it's a deliberate mistake to show that the vampires are not native English speakers.  The idiomatic expression is "safety **tips**".

In addition, the vampires might be difficult to understand because the actors are using a fake "Transylvania" accent, so they pronounce many words differently from how many native speakers do, for example:

> "s" and "th" sounds as "z", ("ze" instead of "the")
>
> some "th" sounds as "s", ("sinking" instead of "thinking" or "sought" instead of "thought").
>
> "w" and "wh" sounds as "v", ("vat" instead of "what")
>
> final "g" sounds as "k", ("brink" instead of "bring")

They aren't all 100% consistent with this accent, and they don't all use the same accent, which makes it even more complicated.  But perhaps that's part of the humor.

Also, they deliberately mispronounce some words, like "skellington" instead of "skeleton".